# Unable to download Managed package custom labels using Eclipse/MavensMate

Tags: managed-package

My intention is to deploy custom labels+Translation,which are a part of a Managed package from sandbox to prod. 
I am trying to download them to eclipse/Mavensmate first so that i can deploy to production from there,but i am not able to download the managed package labels& translation, I am able to download only the unmanaged package related labels & translation.
Tried in Mavensmate by setting the  "mm_ignore_managed_metadata" : false in the .settings file & refreshed the code, but all in vain. I do not see the labels related to Managed packages.

Comment: Am i missing something... when you will install manage package in production.. won't these automatically come ? Why you need to deploy  from sandbox to production?

Comment: This is my first task with managed packages, so not sure how it works. If i had to deploy the label changes through change set, how  should i do?